# C++: Does returning a lambda through a non-owning object make calling it UB?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

I've created a non-owning analogue to `std::function` (`mtap::function_view`). It works by storing a `const void*` to the callable object and a helper function to call it in a type-erased manner.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace mtap {
  template <class T>
  struct function_view;

  template <class R, class... Args>
  struct function_view<R(Args...)> {
  private:
    template <std::invocable<Args...> F>
    requires std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>, R>
    static R call_fn(const void* ptr, Args&&... args) {
      return std::invoke(*reinterpret_cast<const F*>(ptr), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

  public:
    const void* fn;
    R (*caller)(const void*, Args&&...);
    
    function_view() = delete;
    
    template <std::invocable<Args...> F>
    requires std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>, R>
    function_view(const F& value) : fn(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(std::addressof(value))), caller(call_fn<F>) {
    }
    
    R operator()(Args&&... args) {
      return caller(fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  };
}  // namespace mtap
```

If I was to return an `mtap::function_view` constructed with a local lambda, then call it later, is it undefined behaviour? Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <mtap/function_view.hpp>

mtap::function_view<int64_t()> time_getter() {
  return []() -> int64_t {
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
  };
}

int main() {
  auto fn = time_getter();
  std::cout << (fn() / 1000) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The behavior is implementation-defined per [\[conv.lval\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.lval#3.3), which is applied to `fn` in `return caller(fn, …);`

Comment: Far as I can tell, you have a function that, in effect, returns a pointer to a temporary object. By the time you are calling the lambda, it has already been destroyed, which is UB. You are only getting away with it because the lambda in the example is stateless and doesn't actually use its `this` pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik _By the time you are calling the lambda, it has already been destroyed, which is UB._ What exactly is UB.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. In `std::invoke(*reinterpret_cast<const F*>(ptr) ...)` where `ptr` points to an already-destroyed temporary. `function_view` doesn't merely pass an invalid pointer around - it dereferences it and tries to access members through it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik _Accessing an object after its lifetime has ended_ Access is specified as only happening through glvalues of scalar type. `F` isn't scalar type. _`function_view` doesn't merely pass an invalid pointer around_ It may never pass an invalid pointer value around if an implementation specifies that [conv.lval] doesn't produce an invalid pointer value when reading an object containing it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer There's `*reinterpret_cast<const F*>(ptr)`, followed by an attempt to call `operator()` on the resulting `F` object. How can this not be UB, when that `F` object is already dead? `time_getter()` constructs a temporary lambda, then takes its address, wraps it in `function_view` and returns the latter. Then the lambda is destroyed. Then the program attempts to call `operator()` on the already-dead lambda object. Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ah, if you mean "accessing" for class member access, then yes, it is undefined. But `ptr` is neither guaranteed to be an invalid pointer value nor a pointer to the old dead object. The value is implementation-defined.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Say I have `int* f() { int x=0; return &x;}` You seem to be saying that, if I write `(*f())++` this is undefined behavior; but if I write `int* p = f(); (*p)++;` this is implementation-defined behavior, because an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is introduced. Maybe this is so, but to me it looks like a distinction without a difference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik _You seem to be saying that_ For the second part you are right. For the first part — I'm not sure what happens to pointer values which are «in flight», because I read https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.stc.general#4.sentence-1 as replacing all pointer values stored in objects of pointer types with an invalid pointer value.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer If a value of an "in-flight" pointer doesn't necessarily become invalid, then could you really say that `p` is invalid (in the second part)? `x` is destroyed before `p` is initialized, so if "in-fligh" pointer is somehow not an invalid pointer, then `p` wouldn't be either. (What *would* it be, in your opinion, I don't understand). It seems to me that your reading can't be the intended meaning, as it leads to absurd outcomes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik _If a value of an "in-flight" pointer doesn't necessarily become invalid, then could you really say that p is invalid (in the second part)? `x` is destroyed before `p` is initialized_ I wonder did you look at the assembly code or in the standard to come to this conclusion. If the former then it is a wrong way — to judge about C++ behavior by what an implementation has produced. It may be possible that the `return` statement initializes not the object designated by `p`, there is a CWG issue, but anyway there is an object storing `x` address before `x` destruction.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer If there's some object storing an address of `x` before `x` is destroyed, then isn't that object's value replaced with an invalid pointer value when `x` is destroyed? You seemed to be unsure about that earlier. Is that object not the "in-flight pointer" you mentioned before?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik [stmt.return] says that the [prvalue result object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lval#def:result_object) is initialized before destruction of function's «local» objects. And the result object is one designated by `p`. However, there is an [issue](http://wg21.link/cwg2434) saying that implementations shall be allowed to create temporaries not only of class types. So here it may be a temporary object of `int` type. Anyway, there is an object storing a pointer to `x` before `x` dies.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Now, to the `(*f())++` case. [stmt.return] doesn't discuss the case when there is no result object, even though [basic.lval] says «a non-discarded prvalue that is used to compute the value of an operand of a built-in operator … has no result object». I think it is a defect. [stmt.return]+[expr.call] have a lot of them when they tryna specify the relation between a function invocation (result) and its `return` statement. _Is that object not the "in-flight pointer" you mentioned before?_ «in-flight value» is a value not stored anywhere.

Comment: Testing against UBSan does not raise any errors.

Comment: @itzjackyscode Try a capturing lambda that actually does something with the variable it captured. Otherwise, it "works" for the same reason this "works": `struct C{void f() { std::cout << "Hello"; }}; ((C*)nullptr)->f();`